# Issues with the view of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, lucee

I am running this query

```
select owner, recovery, status, collation, version 
from vw_db_info 
where name = 'test100'
```

And I get this error:

> Error Executing Database Query.
>   Invalid object name 'vw_db_info'.

Is there another way I get the same information without that above and I seemingly not found the view in database, not in system.

Comment: Your view is not defined.  Perhaps it is in another database or a non-default schema.

Comment: first question:, is there any kind of view, as far as i know there is not, and if now, what other query i can use to get the same results, i am no db expert

Comment: or how can i create that view to get that above information, this is an old code which i am trying to run

Comment: Where do you get the name of this view from? Is it a view you normally create yourself? Or is it created from a third party software system perhaps? I've never heard of this view, and from what I can tell: if you haven't created it yourself, it will not be in your database.

Comment: Most/all of that information is in the [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql) system view. Different columns names, though.

Comment: ok, Thanks byt the sys.databases does not return me everything i need , in the case i need `owner, recovery, status, collation, version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definition of your custom view `vw_db_info` so at a guess, maybe this is what you want:

```
select 
p.Name, 
D.recovery_model_desc, 
D.state_desc, 
D.collation_name, 
D.compatibility_level, 
@@VERSION
from sys.databases D
left outer JOIN
SYS.server_principals p
on d.owner_sid = p.principal_id
where D.name = 'TEST100'
```